# gcc/g++ and multiple definitions of global variables

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have several .h/.cpp files, each of these ought to have files called "common.h / common.cpp" as I re-use its definitions in the rest of my files. The common.h file defines some intentionally global variables.

I work under Linux and gcc 4.4.7.

Compuler does job OK, but g++ linker complains for many cases like:

```
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/StoreData2/spacewx.o:(.data+0x200): multiple definition of `nmdata::names`
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/StoreData2/StoreData2.o:(.data+0x200): first defined here
```

and as such I am not getting a successfull build. Please advice how to get rid of this error, and keep these global variables. I only use functional programming (using C++ libraries such as boost) and no own namespaces/objects so far.

Comment: Where's you minimal example?

Comment: You really didn't think any of the source doe might be relevant?

Comment: Consider using `extern` keyword. If you can give us some minimal code I can give you a good answer.

Comment: Probably want `extern sometype names;` in your headerfile.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it just happens to any field defined in common.h and used by couple of .cpp files. My minimal example would be insanely trivial

Comment: @AskarIbragimov: So what? Post it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath no need. There is a very nice answer now from person who seen not to have an issue with this. I really appreciate his attitude.

Comment: @AskarIbragimov It's not about attitude. It's about following the rules of the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say that your global header is (`global.h`):

```
#ifndef _GLOBAL_H
#define _GLOBAL_H

int g_a;

#endif
```

If you have two source files including `global.h`: `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` like this:

`a.cpp`

```
#include "global.h"
/* some source */
```

`b.cpp`

```
#include "global.h"
/* some source */
```

After preprocessing they will look like this (included files are expanded):

`a.cpp`

```
int g_a;
/* some source */
```

`b.cpp`

```
int g_a;
/* some source */
```

So, if you compile those source files, global variable `int g_a` will be defined in two object files. So the linker will complain about multiple definitions.

To overcome this problem, you will need `extern` keyword in the header. `extern` keyword tells the compiler that the variable is defined somewhere else. So, no new global object entries will be written to the object files.

Change the `global.h` as following:

```
#ifndef _GLOBAL_H
#define _GLOBAL_H

extern int g_a;

#endif
```

So, there will be no `int g_a` entry will be written to object files. But that would cause undefined symbol error in linking. To overcome that define `int g_a` in `a.cpp` or `b.cpp` but not in both.

`b.cpp`

```
#include "global.h"
int g_a;
/* some source */
```

Answer (score 1):

Each variable or function in your program can only be *defined* once, in one compiliation unit.  If you *define* anything in more than one compilation unit, you'll generally get a link error like you see, though officially, it is Undefined Behavior, so the compiler might not give a diagnostic and your program will just misbehave.

You can have multiple *declarations* of things in your program, so generally you set things up so that your head files have *ONLY* declarations, with all the definitions in the .cpp files.